# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Aborted (core dumped) in 2d array creation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am creating one 2d array which has dynamic row and dynamic column size.

I need to allocate memory in main function. And getting value, printing should happen in a different function

My code work as my expectation but finally I got an runtime error
 `free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Aborted (core dumped)`

But I am using only one free function at last in main. What is the reason for this error.
I am using gcc compiler.

Example execution:[image]

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio_ext.h>

void arr_value_getting_printing(int row,int col,int ** ptr)
{
    // Getting element from the user
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&ptr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    

    // 2d array rows modification
    char ch;
    __fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Do you want to increase the Row(y/n):\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch == 'y')
    {
    int new_row=0;
    printf("Enter the final row size (already 0 to %d row present):\n",row-1);
    scanf("%d",&new_row); 
    int**p =realloc(ptr, new_row * sizeof(int*));
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        ptr = p;
        // Getting the elements for the Newly created rows
        for(int i = row ; i < new_row ; i++ ) 
        {
            printf("Enter the elements for the new rows[%d]:",i);
            // Allocating memory for Newly created rows
            ptr[i] = calloc(col,sizeof(int)); 
            for(int j = 0; j < col ; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&ptr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        row = new_row;
    }   
    }


    // 2d array column modification
    __fpurge(stdin);
    // This arr pointer used for if any modification happens on any of the column it store the newly added column size
    int * arr = calloc(row,sizeof(int)); 
    printf("Do you want to increase the Col(y/n):\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    while(ch == 'y')
    {
    int Row,Column;
    printf("Which Rows col you want to increase(Rows 0 - %d):\n",row-1);
    scanf("%d",&Row); // which row i need to modify
    printf("Enter the new col size(current col size %d):\n",col+arr[Row]);
    scanf("%d",&Column); // final column size
    int *temp = realloc (ptr[Row],Column); // roallocating
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        ptr[Row] = temp;
        // updating the newly added column
        arr[Row] = Column - col; 
        printf("Enter the element for the new cols:\n");
        for(int j = col ; j < Column ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&ptr[Row][j]);
        }
    }
    __fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Do you want to continue\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    }


    // Printing the 2d array element
    printf("Printing the updated element array elenent:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col + arr[i] ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



int main()
{
    int row , col;
    printf("Enter the row and cols:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
    int **ptr=calloc(row,sizeof(int*)); // 2d arr row creation 
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
        {
            ptr[i] = calloc(col,sizeof(int)); // 2d array column creation 
        } 

arr_value_getting_printing(row,col,ptr); //function call
    }
    free(ptr); // Freeing only one time
}
```

Comment: You need to match each calloc/malloc with a free so 1 is not enough.  What input do you use to trigger the error?

Comment: Please revise question with exact input (and delete the comment).

Comment: Why do you create a new arr `arr`?  And why do you use `*col + arr[i]` as the new column count?

Comment: This `arr` used for when I print the 2d array. In my `example execution` I add the extra three column in 0th row ( I actually entered 5, it means already there is 2 column present and I need to add 3 more new column). And the 3 is stored in corresponding row index(arr[0] = 3). when printing 0th row only need to run 5 time(col already consist of 2 + arr[0] consist of 3). Here I am using `calloc` for arr allocate the reason is I want all the element to be zero when the initialision stage.

Comment: You can just realloc each row.  See what I did in the answer below.

Comment: In my case I am not returning ptr. So the changes made in the function `arr_value_getting_printing()`  not going to affect the ptr present in the main. Can explain in how the ptr generate run time error. What happening there, i am bit confusing that line `free(ptr)`.

Comment: In `main()` you do `int **ptr = calloc(...)` let's say `&ptr == A1` and `ptr == A2`.  We then call `arr_value_getting_printing(int **ptr2, ...)` so `&ptr2 == A3` and `ptr2 == A2`.  When we successfully change the row count with `realloc()` we get `ptr2 = A4` and `realloc()` presumably does a `free(A2)` internally.  Then we return to `main()` and do `free(A2)` and we have a double free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `arr_value_getting_printing()` when you resize the number of rows with `realloc(ptr, ...)`, `realloc()` will internally free what `ptr` (`A2`), and upon success the program assign the address of the new block to `ptr` (`A4`)..  The key insight is that variables is passed by value so `main():ptr` and `arr_value_getting_printing():ptr` are two different variables. When you return to `main()` the `ptr` still contains the address of the old block `A2` so `free(ptr)` will result in a double free (of A2).

The usual approach is pass in the address of what you trying to modify, but in this case it would result in being labeled a 3-star programmer (not good).  Return the updated pointer instead.  Caller also need the new row count so I suggest you pass in the address of both `row` and `col`.

The program sorta supports a unique column size per row, but you don't store those column sizes in a way that caller have access to them so I simplified your program to use 1 column size across all rows.  Also moved the print routine to caller just to show it working there.

Prefer passing a variable instead of a type to `sizeof`.  It leads to less code duplication and it's a mechanical transformation of the variable:

```
  int *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
  int **bar = malloc(sizeof *bar);
```

(Partially fixed) Check the return value of all `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` calls.  I think it's a good idea to use `calloc()` for the pointers but individual values are being overwritten so `malloc()` makes more sense.  The error handling code now returns to caller instead of continuing on.

(Not fixed) Check new_row and new_col that they are larger (to match prompt).  In `main()` you want to check that `row > 0` and `col > 0` as zero sized array are undefined.

(Not fixed) Check return value of all `scanf()` calls otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

int **arr_value_getting_printing(int *row, int *col, int **ptr) {
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for(int r = 0; r < *row; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < *col ; c++)
            scanf("%d",&ptr[r][c]);

    __fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Do you want to increase the Row(y/n):\n");
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch == 'y') {
        printf("Enter the final row size (already 0 to %d row present):\n", *row-1);
        int new_row;
        scanf("%d", &new_row);
        int **p = realloc(ptr, new_row * sizeof *p);
        if (!p) {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
            return ptr;
        }
        ptr = p;
        for(int r = *row ; r < new_row ; r++ ) {
            printf("Enter the elements for the new rows[%d]:", r);
            ptr[r] = malloc(*col * sizeof *ptr[r]);
            for(int c = 0; c < *col ; c++)
                scanf("%d",&ptr[r][c]);
        }
        *row = new_row;
    }

    __fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Do you want to increase the Col(y/n):\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch == 'y') {
        int new_col;
        printf("Enter the new col size (current col size %d):\n", *col);
        scanf("%d",&new_col);
        printf("Enter the element for the new cols:\n");
        for(int r = 0; r < *row; r++) {
            int *p = realloc(ptr[r], sizeof *p * new_col);
            if(!p) {
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
                // note some columns may be *col others new_col,
                // so better approach is probably to free all
                // rows and ptr and return NULL.
                return ptr;
            }
            ptr[r] = p;
            for(int c = *col; c < new_col; c++)
                scanf("%d", &ptr[r][c]);
        }
        *col = new_col;
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter the row and cols:\n");
    int row , col;
    scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
    int **ptr = calloc(row, sizeof *ptr);
    if (!ptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
        ptr[i] = malloc(col * sizeof *ptr[i]);
    ptr = arr_value_getting_printing(&row, &col, ptr);

    printf("Printing the updated element array elenent:\n");
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < col; c++)
            printf("%d%c", ptr[r][c], c + 1 < col ? ' ' : '\n');
        free(ptr[r]);
    }
    free(ptr);
}
```

and example run:

```
Enter the row and cols:
2 2
Enter the elements:
1 2 3 4
Do you want to increase the Row(y/n):
y
Enter the final row size (already 0 to 1 row present):
3
Enter the elements for the new rows[2]:5 6
Do you want to increase the Col(y/n):
y
Enter the new col size (current col size 2):
3
Enter the element for the new cols:
7 8 9
Printing the updated element array element:
1 2 7
3 4 8
5 6 9
```

and valgrind is happy:

```
==396782== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```